# How to create a Case function that branches based off a searched substring?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to apply the following logic in Azure Logic App.

```
if (contains(inputText, "test1")):
     do action 1
elseif (contains(inputText, "test2")):
     do action 2
elseif (contains(inputText, "test3")):
     do action 3
```

I tried using Switch, but I can only use equals for each Case. Is there another way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly but you can try a couple of approaches.

##### Condition Action

The condition action allows you to perform a number of different types of searches/comparisons, the ugly thing about it is the nested view of the flow.

This example is looking for **Test1** in the first condition and then **Test2** if that first returns false.

You can build on that as need be.

[image: Condition]

##### Evaluated Variable

You can use the `indexOf` expression in an IF statement but depending on how much nesting you want to include, it could become fairly nasty as well.

```
if(greater(indexOf(variables('Input Text'), 'Test1'), -1), 'Test1', if(greater(indexOf(variables('Input Text'), 'Test2'), -1), 'Test2', if(greater(indexOf(variables('Input Text'), 'Test3'), -1), 'Test3', '')))
```

After that result, you can use your `Switch` expression to evaluate the results and do something with it.

[image: IF]

This is the result ...

[image: Result]

Comment: I was afraid of that. Was hoping there was a way to do it without nesting a bunch of if statements for each case. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Maybe use an Azure Function then.

Comment: Also, you may not like the answer but based on your question, do you think it should be flagged as the answer?  After all, I did provide other ways to achieve what you wanted.